# regex to remove the last word if it contains a character

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex in Python that will remove the last word from a string if it contains a certain character, in this case '#', and in other appearances of that character '#', only the character is removed, not the word.

So the string:

> What a #great day #happy

would become:

> What a great day

so far I have tried

```
    entry = re.sub('(?<=#)\w+','',entry)
```

but this removes all words containing '#'.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Before you ask a question here, you should make some reasonable effort to solve it yourself, and report "what you have tried" and what you are having trouble with. Since you have already heard about regexes, you need to learn how to use them.

Comment: apologies alexis, I've edited the post. I'm new here.

Comment: No prob. Looks like you have an answer already; if it solves your problem, "accept" it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'''(?x)    # VERBOSE mode
                 [#]     # literal #
                 |       # or
                 \s*     # zero-or-more spaces
                 \w*     # zero-or-more alphanumeric characters 
                 [#]     # literal #
                 \w*     # zero-or-more alphanumeric characters 
                 $       # end of line
                 ''',
             '', # substitute matched text with an empty string
             'What a #great day #happy'))
```

yields

```
What a great day
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s='What a #great day #happy'

# Test if the last word has a '#'
if re.match('#',s.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]):
    # Deal with everything but last word and do replacement         
    print re.sub('#', '',s.rsplit(' ', 1)[0])  
else:
    # Else replace all '#' 
    print re.sub('#', '',s) 

>>> What a great day
```

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for adding the comments, I now understand how it works.